# Looking for a book series written for youth or young readers

Tags: story-identification, books

The word 'Galaxy' is on the back cover. They are hardback books but fairly thin; Possibly short stories. One has 'Emergency' something in the title, maybe 'Emergency Medical' or something like that. Not sure.. I didn't read them but wanted to and now can't find them. Not sure when they were released but they looked like older books, but they could be 70s, 80s or perhaps even 90s. I just don't know. Thanks. That is about all I can remember about them. I'm tying to find the name of the series.

Thanks but that doesn't look like them. These are hard books, thin, mainly dark blue or black cover work front and back. I think there is a little picture of a galaxy on the back with the word galaxy on the back, but otherwise the back is plain.

Answer (score 7):

Could be [Galaxy Science Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Science_Fiction) magazine and/or [Galaxy Science Fiction Novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Science_Fiction_Novels).

[image]

Comment: @Angie You should put any further comments or responses down here so you don't muddy up the original question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, if you can remember any other details that would help identification, feel free to add them. Good try @user13500.

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy magazine used to put out books called "The Nth Galaxy Reader" with reprints of stories appearing in the last year or so.

I used to have the **Fourth Galaxy Reader**.

[image: "The Fourth Galaxy Reader" for visual reference]